# Scaling input into a recursive neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a dataframe with 4 columns:

```
                          PM10       temperatura  wind     CO
data                                                        
2016-01-01 01:00:00      100.6892         -8.2    2.0    0.722
2016-01-01 02:00:00      101.7332         -8.3    3.0    0.735
2016-01-01 03:00:00       97.1396         -9.1    2.0    0.732
2016-01-01 04:00:00       72.7100         -9.1    3.0    0.662
2016-01-01 05:00:00       61.5392         -9.6    3.0    0.625
```

The data is hourly, but as an input to the neural network I take chunks of 24 tuples (so one day) (PM10,temperatura, wind, CO).

My output is a 24 hour average of PM10 from the next day. My question is: Should I scale the data or normalize it before inputing it into my neural network? I tried a couple of approaches, which give me very bad results. My approaches:

1. MinMaxScaler
2. standardscaler
3. some transformation with tanh

I will add that the neural network I am inputing it into is recursive. Another question is what mean and standard deviation should I use in order to retrieve the original value from the output after scaling. (should it be average of all PM10 or should it be average after slicing the data into 24 pieces chunks)?

Comment: If you want to output PM10 Average of 24 values, you should also train on that, so maybe add a feature PM10_24avg to your dataset. Normailizing is a good idea, Its not the reason for your bad results

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel Thank you for your response, so in your opinion what variables from my dataset would be suitable to predict average of PM10 for the next day? Should I make averages from all variables?

Comment: depending on how many data points you have, i would create the output variable PM10PerDay . Can you share your data?

Comment: Here I shared the data, after splitting into daily chunks (24 hours)  I have 361 records. https://github.com/szczor/sharing/tree/master

Comment: Ok, it's a bit problematic i guess, that your dataset only has the beginnings and ends of the years, everything in between (from ferbruary to november) is missing...

Comment: For example, i was able to train a Regression Model with a mean error of 16 on predicting the PM10, based on the Temperature, wind and CO. Thats not what you were trying to do, but just a small performance hint..

Comment: I intentionally deleted the period from february to november, as I want to predict outcome for the beginning of the year hence believe that the data I deleted is irrelevant. Why is that problematic? Did you scale the data for your regression model?

Comment: Yes I did, but it doesn't really make a difference